# Finding the Automorphism and Image

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $f: G \to G$.  Let $G$ be contained in $\text{GL}_2(\mathbb{R})$ and let $G$ be the Matrix 
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\pm 1 & 0\\
0 & \pm 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

The question asked to check that $G$ is a group and then determine automorphism of $G$ and the Image of $f$. I understand how to show that $G$ is a group, but would appreciate any help on showing the Automorphism of G and the Image of $f$. Thank you

Comment: LaTeX tutorial: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 0):

What are the generators of the group?

That is the first question you need to answer.

---

Here's the second half of the question

Assume $\phi : G \to G$ is an automorphism

Then $\phi $ is an isomorphism which is onto. So for any $y \in G $ there exists $x \in G $ s.t. $\phi (x) = y $

This shows $\phi (G) = G $

Now you just need to show that your function is an automorphism.

Comment: It seems clear to me that this answer is a valid hint to find the automorphisms of the group G. Thus it should not be downvoted or closed. It could have been made more clear, however.

Comment: Excuse me I keep forgetting comments and answers are distinct. Is it possible to move this to comment status?

Comment: There I answered half the question. Hopefully that cleans this up.

Answer (score 0):

Of course the identity is an autpmorphism. You also have the automorphism $$A \mapsto -A$$  (check $-A$ belongs to G). The image of both is the whole G group.